# How to prove events A and B are exhaustive [Probability]

Tags: probability

Lets say, P(A) = $\frac{2}{3}$ and P(B) = $\frac{1}{4}$ and P(A|B) = $\frac{2}{3}$

How do I prove that events A and B are exhaustive?

I thank you in advance!

Comment: Find $p(A\cap B)$. Hence find $p(A\cup B)$.

Comment: I would interpret "exhaustive" as meaning that $\Pr(A\cup B)=1$. But $\Pr(A\cup B)\le \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)=\frac{11}{12}$, so with the probabilities as currently stated $A$ and $B$ do not seem to be exhaustive.

Comment: Is it possible you meant to say "prove that events $A$ and $B$ are independent?"

Comment: [UPDATE]. 

So.

P(A ∩ B) = P(A|B) * P(B).
P(A ∩ B) = $\frac{2}{3}$ * $\frac{1}{4}$.
P(A ∩ B) = $\frac{1}{6}$.

P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B).
P(A ∪ B) = $\frac{2}{3}$ + $\frac{1}{4}$.
P(A ∪ B) = $\frac{1}{6}$.

From the definition of exhaustive, we can say that A and B are not exhaustive?

Am I correct in my working out?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct - they are not exhaustive. We have $p(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{6}$ and $p(A\cup B)=\frac{3}{4}<1$.

Comment: However, they are independent, because $p(A\cap B)=p(A)p(B)=\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: I see, I understand now!!! Thank you @almagest for your time and confirmation!!!

Comment: And thank you @AndréNicolas for your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: @ReeLink: You are welcome.  With these particular numbers, we were able to show $A$ and $B$ are not exhaustive without using the conditional probability information, that is, without computing $\Pr(A\cap B)$. But in other situations your full computation would be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First we must find the intersection in order to find the union**

P(A ∩ B) = P(A|B) * P(B)

P(A ∩ B) = $\frac{2}{3}$ * $\frac{1}{4}$

P(A ∩ B) = $\frac{1}{6}$

**Now we can find the union.**

P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B)

P(A ∪ B) = $\frac{2}{3}$ + $\frac{1}{4}$ - $\frac{1}{6}$

P(A ∪ B) = $\frac{3}{4}$

**From the definition of exhaustive, we can say that A and B are not exhaustive.**

*Definition of exhaustive in probability:* http://www.engineeringintro.com/statistics/what-is-probability/exhaustive-events/